# Error connecting to http://localhost:8000/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: identityserver4

I host my identity server use address  http://10.2.5.90:8000 and use nginx map https://10.2.5.90:8888 to http://10.2.5.90:8000.

When i tried to request discovery document like [quickstart](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) in client, **"Error connecting to http://localhost:8000/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.."** occurred.

I tried to change Issuer to https address and used customized DiscoveryDocumentRequest. But it was not work.

When I remove the nginx and access http://10.2.5.90:8000, It worked well.

IdentityServer:Startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...other codes
    var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

        options.IssuerUri = "https://10.2.5.90:8888";
    });
    // ...other codes
}
```

Client: Program.cs

```cs
private static async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var req = new DiscoveryDocumentRequest
    {
        Address = "https://10.2.5.90:8888",
        Policy = new DiscoveryPolicy
        {
            ValidateIssuerName = false,
            ValidateEndpoints = false,
        }
    };
    var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(req);
    if (disco.IsError)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(disco.Error);
        // output: Error connecting to http://localhost:8000/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks. Object reference not set to an instance of an object..
        return null;
    }

    // ...other codes
}
```

#### Edit:

I changed the code when config identity server and it works when running discovery.

```cs
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.PublicOrigin = "https://10.2.5.90:8888";
});
```

However, I still couldn't access my api. The error is **Exception occurred while processing message.IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'http://localhost:8000/.well-known/openid-configuration'** and I'm researchig the solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to change de Authority property in your api. The api needs to access to the discovery endpoint through nginx (port 8888):

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Audience = "api1";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
        options.Authority = "https://10.2.5.90:8888";
    });
```

If you have a public IP and your backend farm use internal uris you can adjust your host uri data in the middleware. Try to put this middleware in the first position:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.Scheme = "https";
    context.Request.Host = new HostString("10.2.5.90.8888");
    context.Request.PathBase = "yourApplicationPathBase";

    await next.Invoke();
});
```

Of course, you have to parameterize this strings by environment in your configuration.

Comment: Thank you, it works! However, my api and IdServer would be in the same net in production environment, if the authority woud be the real address(https://mydomain), it would take more networks.

Comment: I understand you. Please, try out the solution I give you in the second part of my answer.